# normalize the rows of numpy array based on a custom function

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array. I want to normalized each rows based on this formula

`x_norm = (x-x_min)/(x_max-x_min)`

, where `x_min` is the minimum of each row and `x_max` is the maximum of each row. Here is a simple example:

```
a = np.array(
         [[0, 1 ,2],
          [2, 4 ,7],
          [6, 10,5]
 ])
```

and desired output:

```
a = np.array([
          [0, 0.5 ,1],
          [0, 0.4 ,1],
          [0.2, 1 ,0]
    ])
```

Thank you

Comment: by custom function you mean ufunc ?

Comment: I don't know what is ufunc. I want to normalized based on the function that I provided in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use raw numpy operations:

```
x = np.array(
         [[0, 1 ,2],
          [2, 4 ,7],
          [6, 10,5]
 ])

x_norm = ((x.T-x.min(1))/(x.max(1)-x.min(1))).T
# OR
x_norm = (x-x.min(1)[:,None])/(x.max(1)-x.min(1))[:,None]
```

output:

```
array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.4, 1. ],
       [0.2, 1. , 0. ]])
```

*NB. if efficiency matters, save the result of `x.min(1)` in a variable as it is used twice*

Answer (score 0):

You could use [np.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
a = np.array(
         [[0, 1 ,2],
          [2, 4 ,7],
          [6, 10,5]
 ])

def scaler(x):
    return (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())   
    
np.apply_along_axis(scaler, axis=1, arr=a)

Output:

array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.4, 1. ],
       [0.2, 1. , 0. ]])
```